# PHP - set datetime as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD

Tags: php

I have a PHP string currently in this format.  How do I get it to return as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD?

```
2011-10-19 10:29:05
```

Comment: What timezone should be used?

Comment: What's the code you run into a problem actually? What does not work?

Answer (score 6):

I found the PHP datetime format ('c') did what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple like iso standard

```
echo date('c');
```

Comment: You should work a little more on your answer. Like giving the source like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, or telling that date accepts many formats. Good luck with more answers in the future.

Comment: This answer aint correct. It will output [..]Thh:mm:ssTZD - but the seconds should not be printed. The format mentioned in the initial post is used e.g. with google sitemaps, btw.

Answer (score 1):

He's already got it in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, he wants it in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD.

```
$date_before='2011-10-19 10:29:05';

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_before)) . "T" . date('H:iP',strtotime($date_before));
```